# how to erase tkinter label after it printed correct

Tags: python, tkinter

ok so i made an if statement that it displays a label saying correct if the answer is correct now i have problem with erasing the label because destroy() wont work and i need to get rid of it to show my next question btw im new to tkinter so bare with me  so can u help me thx

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("800x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Quiz App', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
label1.pack()

txtbox = tk.Entry(window, width=50) # Create Entry in global namespace

def chkanswer():
    useranswer = txtbox.get()       # Get contents from Entry
    if useranswer == 'cs':
        lblcorrect = tk.Label(window, text='Correct').pack()

    else:
        lbl = tk.Label(window, text='Wroooong').pack()


def playbuttonclicked():
    label1.destroy()
    playbtn.destroy()
    quitbtn.destroy()
    label2 = tk.Label(window, text='What is the short form of computer science', font=("Arial Bold", 10)).pack()
    txtbox.place(x=250, y=400)
    useranswer = txtbox.get()
    submitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', command=chkanswer).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

playbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Play', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=playbuttonclicked)
playbtn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

def quitbuttonclicked():
    window.destroy()

quitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Quit', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=quitbuttonclicked)
quitbtn.place(x=530, y=570)

window.mainloop()
```

thx

Comment: First `lblcorrect` is a local variable which cannot be accessed outside `chkanswer()`.  Second even it is declared as global, it is `None` because it is the result of `pack()`, not `tk.Label(...)`.

Comment: can you explain more please thanks

Comment: I cannot explain more.

Comment: no like using code format like edit my code  show me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i cant remove the label that says 'correct' after it displays

Answer (score 0):

> how to erase tkinter label after it printed correct
>
> I made an if statement that it displays a label saying correct if the
> answer is correct now I have problem with erasing the label because
> destroy() wont work and I need to get rid of it to show my next
> question.

The problem can be solved.

- Move `lblcorrect` widget outside of function.
- You need a `lblcorrect` widget and use `.configure` to update the quiz in
  the `chkanswer` function.
- Move and split the `label2` widget  and layout after
  `quitbuttonclicked` function.
- On line 24, comment out `#quitbtn.destroy()`. We need the quit button
  for activity.
- Add `label2.configure` in line 25.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("800x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Quiz App', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
label1.pack()

txtbox = tk.Entry(window, width=50) # Create Entry in global namespace

def chkanswer():
    useranswer = txtbox.get()       # Get contents from Entry
    if useranswer == 'cs':
        lblcorrect.configure(text='Correct') 
    else:
        lblcorrect.configure(text='Wroooong')


def playbuttonclicked():
    label1.destroy()
    playbtn.destroy()
    #quitbtn.destroy()
    label2.configure(text='What is the short form of computer science')
     
    txtbox.place(x=250, y=400)
    useranswer = txtbox.get()
    submitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', command=chkanswer).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

playbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Play', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=playbuttonclicked)
playbtn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

def quitbuttonclicked():
    window.destroy()

label2 = tk.Label(window, font=("Arial Bold", 10))
label2.pack()    

lblcorrect = tk.Label(window)
lblcorrect.pack(pady=10)    

quitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Quit', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=quitbuttonclicked)
quitbtn.place(x=530, y=570)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]